# OctoPrint Plugin that triggers python and bash scripts to control RaspiCam?

Tags: python, bash, flask, raspberry-pi, octoprint

I'm currently building a new plugin for OctoPrint running on Rasberry Pi 3. What I want it to do is to have a HTML front-end tab that contains buttons, which I have already had. Then the button should be able to trigger a bash script to capture the image, and another button to run a python script with OpenCV that will do edge detection and output to the front-end the image after process.

I can do all of those things manually but I have not found a way to automate it. I tried using `flask` as recommended after search but it ran into the "Address already in use" issue because OctoPrint is running on it. So, my question is if there is a way to do such things? In other words, is there a way to trigger HTML buttons to trigger python and bash script in the Raspberry Pi without having the port or socket issue?

The python code got from `flask`, which will be the python code with OpenCV imported and do image processing:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

The HTML code using jinja2, currently using the button to display date and time, but will trigger the python code above and a command line:

```
<html>
<body>

<h1>Java Script</h1>

<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = Date()">
Click me to display Date and Time.</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

And my command line to capture picture from mpjg-streamer is:

```
wget http://localhost:8080/?action=snapshot -O output.jpg
```

If possible, please provide me an example with explanation for it? Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you have many possible problems, and we need to break them up. The "Address already in use" error is something you should be able to deal with by simply running the Flask app on a different port (use `app.run(port=XXXX)` to specify a different port).

Comment: Thanks @YellowShark. I have tried that solution as well; however, if the python script runs on one port and octoprint runs on different port, I don't think the html scrip on octoprint can trigger the python script.